# Don't add row to listview if it has a duplicate value

Tags: vb.net

What i'm trying to do is not add a duplicate row containing a value in to a list view, i tried:

```
Private distinctResults As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
'...
If Not (distinctResults.ContainsKey(GetTextId(columns))) Then
    Dim item As ListViewItem = listViewShowLinks.Items.Add(id) '// ID.
    item.SubItems.Add(subItemUrl)           '// URL.
    item.SubItems.Add(searchId)             '// SEARCH ID.
    item.SubItems.Add(pgex)                 '// PGEX.
    item.SubItems.Add(ms)                   '// MS.
    item.SubItems.Add(GetTextId(columns))   '// TEXT ID.
    item.SubItems.Add(GetPrice(columns).Replace(",", ".")) '// PRICE.
    item.SubItems.Add(GetTextId(columns))   '// TEXT ID.
    item.SubItems.Add(GetPr(columns))       '// PR.
    item.SubItems.Add(GetSr(columns))       '// SR.
    listCopy.Add(item)
    listViewShowLinks.EndUpdate()
End If
```

But it's not working, this value: GetTextId(columns) contains the key i'm looking for, the output is like

10123

10123

10124

10125

etc

It's really the first value (row) i don't want to add. i'm not sure the best way to do this.

any help would be appreciated :)

cheers guys

Graham

Comment: You need to add the IDs that you have used to the distinctResults Dictionary. I'm not sure what you intend to add as the value in the Dictionary. Perhaps you really just need a `List(Of String)`.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a better solution with less code lines :

```
Dim distinctResults As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
Dim isThere As Boolean = False          'This is used to check if the columns are there or is there
For Each vall In distinctResults.Values 'Sort all of the values inside of the Dictionary
    If vall = GetTextId(columns) Then   'Check if it's found
       isThere = True                   'It's found, so set isThere to True
    End If
Next
If isThere = False Then                 'If it hasn't been set to found then do the following
   Dim item As ListViewItem = listViewShowLinks.Items.Add(id) '// ID.
   item.SubItems.Add(subItemUrl)           '// URL.
   item.SubItems.Add(searchId)             '// SEARCH ID.
   item.SubItems.Add(pgex)                 '// PGEX.
   item.SubItems.Add(MS)                   '// MS.
   item.SubItems.Add(GetTextId(columns))   '// TEXT ID.
   item.SubItems.Add(GetPrice(columns).Replace(",", ".")) '// PRICE.
   item.SubItems.Add(GetTextId(columns))   '// TEXT ID.
   item.SubItems.Add(GetPr(columns))       '// PR.
   item.SubItems.Add(GetSr(columns))       '// SR.
   listCopy.Add(item)
   listViewShowLinks.EndUpdate()
End If
```

I hope this is what you need.